# Just another simple math problem

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

> $4+5=9$
>
> $7+9=13$
>
> $11-5=9$
>
> $17+29=\,?$

Find the value of "?"

Comment: Is the order of equations deliberate?

Comment: no. they were random

Comment: Oh... then my answer is probably not correct... I haven't looked at @jafe 's just yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> 17+29=43

Because

> All numbers are presented in base-13

Comment: relevant: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Douglas_Adams#Unsourced

Comment: you got it, it was pretty obvious i suppose @jafe

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Answer

---

<sup>I will denote by a dot to represent multiplication for letters, in order to avoid confusion between $\times =$ times and $X=$ x. 
 (e.g. $A\times B = A\cdot B$).</sup>

---

I have found a pattern for the sums (+), but not the difference (-):

> Let $\max\{A,B\} = A$ if $A>B$ and $\max\{A,B\} = B$ if $B>A$. 
>  Let $\min\{A,B\} = A$ if $A<B$ and $\max\{A,B\} = B$ if $B<A$.

Then,

> $$A+ B=\big(\min\{A,B\}\cdot (\max\{A,B\}+n)\big)-(\max\{A,B\}-1)^2+2-n$$

such that

> $n$ represents the numbered equation it is. $$\begin{align}4+5&=9\tag{$n=1$} \\ 7+9&=13\tag{$n=2$} \\ 11−5&=9\tag{$n=3$} \\ 17+29&=\,\,?\tag{$n=4$}\end{align}$$

Therefore,

> $$\begin{align}4+5&=4(5+1) - (5-1)^2 + 2 - 1 \\ &= 24-16 + 1\\ &= 9.\;\color{green}{\checkmark}\end{align}$$ $$\begin{align}7+9&=7(9+2) - (9-1)^2 + 2 - 2\\ &= 77-64 + 0\\ &= 13.\;\color{green}{\checkmark}\end{align}$$

The pattern doesn't work for $11-5=9$ (because that has a minus instead of a plus), but if I am on the right track, this leaves the answer to be

> $$\begin{align}17+29&=17(29+1)-(29-1)^2+2-4 \\ &= 510 - 784 - 2 \\ &= -276.\end{align}$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: interesting attempt. but it was quite simple actually, you took it to be more difficult than it was.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid If $4+5=9$, would $5+4=9$? (In your puzzle, I mean.)

Comment: yes, it would .

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I looked at **jafe**'s answer. *Facepalm.*

Comment: ha ha, simplest answer was the right answer here..